# Alternative to if-then-else or case statements

Tags: ruby, string, if-statement, search

I am parsing keywords from a string and wondering if there is an alternative method other than massive if-then-else statements or using a switch statement. Any direction would be helpful

```
application = application.downcase
if(application.include?("ssl"))
     return "SSL"
elsif(application.include?("ssh"))
     return "SSH"
elsif(application.include?("dce"))
     return "DCE"
elsif(application.include?("https"))
     return "HTTPS"
elsif(application.include?("http"))
     return "http"
else
     return "nil"
```

Comment: What do you return in case of `application.include?("https")`?

Comment: Check if it's in an array, upcase it, and special-case http. And then figure out why it's different and make it so it doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way

```
def your_method(application)
  application = application.downcase
  %w(ssl ssh dce https).each do |p|
    return p.upcase if application.include?(p)
  end
  application.include?("http") ? "http" : "nil"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly shorter way

```
%w[SSL SSH DCE HTTPS http].each do |p|
  return p if application =~ /#{p}/i
end
"nil"
```

and this maybe the shortest

```
%w[SSL SSH DCE HTTPS http].find { |p| application =~ /#{p}/i } || "nil"
```

unless you choose a shorter variable name

```
app.upcase[/SSL|SSH|DCE|HTTPS/] || (app =~ /http/i ? "http" : "nil")
```